# What is th macro variable created by HPGENSELECT containing selected effects

Tags: sas, sas-macro

What is the macro variable created by `HPGENSELECT` that contains the selected effects.  In `GLM` select it is `_GLSIND1` but `HPGENSELECT` doesn't appear to populated that field.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to guess that HPGENSELECT doesn't create such a macro variable.

You could test this by using `%PUT _ALL_;` then run HPGENSELECT and then `%PUT _ALL_;` again to see if there are any new macro variables.